# Salt: Pass parameters to custom module executed inside a pillar

Tags: module, salt-stack

I am coding a custom module that is executed inside a pillar (to set a pillar variable) but I need it to retrieve an external parameter.

The idea is to retrieve a parameter from the master server. For example, if I execute

> salt 'myminion' state.highstate

the custom module will be called and it should retrieve a parameter to generate the pillar.

I was looking into options like:

1. Using environment variables: It doesn't work as it seems that the execution modules does nothave access to the shell environment of the salt command.
2. Using command line paramenters: I dont know if it is even possible as I couldn't find any documentation.
3. Using an additional pillar in the command line: It doesn't work as the execution module is executed during pillar evaluation so it does not have access to `__pillar__` or `__salt__['pillar.get']` (both empty).
4. Reading from stdin: Does not workfrom a custom module.
5. Using a file to read info: I didn't even tryied this because it is not an option for me for security reasons. I dont want the information stored.

Any ideas if or how is this possible to do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By:

> a custom module that is executed inside a pillar (to set a pillar variable)

do you mean an [external pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/external_pillars.html)?

If so, passing it parameters is covered in that document:

> You can pass a single argument, a list of arguments or a dictionary of arguments to your pillar:

```
ext_pillar:
  - example_a: some argument
  - example_b:
    - argumentA
    - argumentB
  - example_c:
    keyA: valueA
    keyB: valueB
```

External pillars merge their data into the pillar dictionary, and are "custom modules", so I think that would fit your case.

If that's not what you're trying to do, can you update the question?  Where is this parameter coming from?  Is it different depending on the minion (minion_id is always passed to an external pillar)?

(edit)  Adding a couple links about safely storing secrets:

- [using vault](http://linoxide.com/how-tos/secure-secret-store-vault/)
- [dotgpg](https://cirw.in/blog/dotgpg)
- [blackbox](http://www.slideshare.net/PuppetLabs/black-box-36854162)

Comment: Not necesarilly an external pillar, but I dont want it stored on a file. The parameter would be sensitive information that I would prefer not to be stored anywhere, only on memory during execution time.

Comment: Are you worried about the info being in a file on the *master*?  Or on the minion?  If the former, that means that somebody has to login to the master after it boots and re-enter the data by hand?  If attackers have owned the master, it's all over anyway.  Updating my answer with a couple links that might be helpful.

Comment: I agree that if you have the master compromised you are done. But what I am thinking is that usually if you a backup of your master compromised is might not be a big deal (depending on what you store there). For this reason I would like to not store some information, so the backups of the master are more secure.
The optimal solution would require to add a password on boot so it can operate from that point on. Unfortunately using filesystem encryption is not an option for me as I am using LXC.
What I really wanted was to feed some information to a salt module on its execution in the master.